# How to get indices from a list/ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indices

I have a list which looks like:

```
[[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]
```

I can make it to an array like:

```
array([[0,1,2],
       [1,2,3],
       [2,3,4],
       [3,4,5]])
```

So all together I have 4 rows and each row has 3 columns. Now I want to find the indices of all the elements which are greater than 2, so for the whole matrix, the indices should be:

```
((1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3))
```

Then for each row, I will randomly picked out a col index which indicates a value greater than 2. Now my code is like:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
out = np.ones(4)*-1
cur_row = 0
col_list = []
for r,c in np.nonzero(a>2):
    if r == cur_row:
        col_list.append(c)
    else:
        cur_row = r
        shuffled_list = shuffle(col_list)
        out[r-1] = shuffled_list[0]
        col_list = []
        col_list.append(c)
```

I hope to get a out which looks like:

```
array([-1, 2, 1, 2])
```

However, now when I run my code, it shows

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Anyone knows how I fix this problem? Or how should I do to achieve my goal? I just want to run the code as fast as possible, so any other good ideas is also more than welcome.

Comment: Loop over `zip(*np.nonzero(a>2))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0,1,2],
               [1,2,3],
               [2,3,4],
               [3,4,5]])
indices = np.where(arr>2)

for r, c in zip(*indices):
    print(r, c)
```

Prints

```
1 2
2 1
2 2
3 0
3 1
3 2
```

So, it should work. You can use `itertools.izip` as well, it would even be a better choice in this case.

A pure `numpy` solution (thanks to @AshwiniChaudhary for the proposition):

```
for r, c in np.vstack(np.where(arr>2)).T:
    ...
```

though I'm not sure this will be faster than using izip or zip.

Comment: Of course, it is much simpler with `numpy` but it can easily be done without it.

Comment: He's already loaded numpy, I feel like its even easier, and more pythonic, to use the built in methods

Comment: I still get the ValueError, unpacking zip(*arr) into r,c

Comment: You should use `np.vstack(np.where(arr>2)).T` rather than `zip`.

Comment: @SeanSummers try the exact code I posted. There might be a different mistake in your code you don't notice.

Comment: I did, from a fresh shell. Still too many values to unpack. Python 2.7.5, numpy 1.9.1.

Comment: @SeanSummers oh, that was a misprint. I used `a` in my code and replaced it with `arr` in the answer, yet I forgot to replace it in one place. It should work now. Sorry about that.

Comment: @EliKorvigo still a no go (I edited to include my versions). Does your code work for you in a fresh shell? What versions are you using?

Comment: @SeanSummers there should've been `for r, c in zip(*indices)` not `for r, c in zip(*a)`

Comment: You have re-kindled my faith in cutting and pasting, sir!

Comment: @SeanSummers copy-paste programming is evil, as well as renaming variables manually. I'm very sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @gladys0313 you're welcome. Btw, you've got two answers that do the job, you might consider accepting one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could just compare the array to your value and use where.

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
np.where(a>2)
```

> (array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64),  array([2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
>   dtype=int64))

To get your tuples

```
list(zip(*np.where(a>2)))
```

> [(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]

Answer (score 0):

I have made it out, the code should be:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
out = np.ones(4)*-1
cur_row = 0
col_list = []
for r,c in zip(*(np.nonzero(a>2))):
    if  r == cur_row:
        col_list.append(c)
    else:
        cur_row = r
        shuffle(col_list)
        if len(col_list) == 0:
            out[r-1] = -1
        else:
            out[r-1] = col_list[0]
        col_list = []
        col_list.append(c)

shuffle(col_list)
if len(col_list) == 0:
    out[len(out)-1] = -1
else:
    out[len(out)-1] = col_list[0]
```

The part in the end but outside the forloop is to make sure that the last row will be taken care of.

It works in my case.